# how would I removeClass after a certain div is loaded on a page?

Tags: jquery, load, removeclass

I'm wondering how I can remove a certain class after a specific div is loaded on a page. Does anyone know the appropriate way to do this using jquery?

I'm using a special class for loading and would like it removed on the div once the div has loaded.

Comment: How are you adding the content to the page?

Comment: @lonesomeday the content isn't loaded through ajax actually, its more just a preloader for this certain element which may contain a mountain of text

Comment: What doe you mean with loading a div? With AJAX or on page load? If page load, put this **below** it: `<script>var elm=document.getElementById("yourdiv");elm.className=elm.className.replace("youclass","");</script>`

Comment: @lonesomeday thank you. Do you know anything about animating preloader spinners in jquery? I'm not sure what makes them actually 'spin'

Comment: @Chad They're normally just animated images. See http://www.ajaxload.info/ for instance.

Comment: @lonesomeday oh wow, this is so archaic, i didn't even realize that's how it was done! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are not using AJAX, simply use `removeClass` and put the code in `$(document).ready` so that it won't execute until the dom is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myElement").removeClass("someClass");
});
```